# Resize 2d variable c++

Tags: c++, curl

I am using **C++ CURL** library for sending emails.

My problem is that the text in my email may vary from time to time so I need to change size or dynamically re-allocate my variable:

```
const char *payload_text[10]
```

where 10 might be 20 or even 30
how can I change the size of this variable in my program?

By the way this variable must be allocated as I am using the example from **CURL** library:
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-mail.html

Comment: you use a std::vector<std::string>.

Comment: I wish I could use vector the problem is that the curl library cannt work with vectors only arrays

Comment: @Qouqou that's not a problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you are faced with a data structure that may need to change size you should be thinking `std::vector`.

In this specific case, a `std::vector<std::string>>` is what you want/need.

To pass the vector to a legacy API that expects a C-style array and a size, pass it `std::vector::data()` and `std::vector::size()`. A vector is guaranteed to be using contiguous memory, just like a C-style array, so the two interoperate well.

Answer (score -1):

THANKS
It actually works just some points for others with the same problem:
In the function `payload_source` change the line:

```
data = payload_text.at(upload_ctx->lines_read)
```

What I was afraid to do and in the body of your code where you will fill the email array do the following thing:

```
payload_text.push_back(char_array)
```

The vector itself should be:

```
vector <const char*> payload_text
```

Again thank you all very much

Comment: Ehh. Rather than posting an answer that is not really an answer, you should *accept* the answer that solved your question. And if you want to say thank you, do that in a *comment* to the accepted answer.